# Field value negative based on other field value

Tags: ms-access, vba, default-value

I am working on a small access database for inventory, I have created a tbleInventoryTransaction, where user have to select TransactionType, Addition or removal.

Is there any default value formula or other function which will show the quantity value in negative if user select the the TransactionType "removal".

Comment: You can do this in your form - are you wanting to do in Default Value function of the TransactionType field?

Comment: You're limited by MS-Access - *DefaultValue can be either text or an expression. If the property setting is an expression, it can't contain user-defined functions, Microsoft Access database engine SQL aggregate functions, or references to queries, forms, or other Field objects.*

Comment: Thanks dbmitch, I am trying to do in Quantity Field.

Comment: Are you using a form for the user to enter data? If so what are form fields called for Quantity and TransactionType?

Comment: Thanks everyone, below Gustav answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbox for display must be named differently than "Quantity", say, txtQuantity. For this, set its *ControlSource* to:

```
=IIf([TransactionType]="Removal",-[Quantity],[Quantity])
```